# All material went black when Material output set to cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

When I change my Material Output from all to cycles, the material went black

This is what I want to do [How to EXPORT MATERIALS from Blender to Unity 2023](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yloupOUjMOA&ab_channel=RigorMortisTortoise)

When rendered with cycles the material appears normally

How do I fix this, Thank you

with eevee

[image]

with cycles

[image]

[image]

Comment: As Rich says in his answer, the default is having the material output set to _All_. Using only one of them almost always only makes sense if you want to have different material settings for _Cycles_ and _Eevee_. But since you linked a tutorial as what you were trying to do, I wonder why on Earth did you change it from _All_ to _Eevee_ or _Cycles_ later? They have it at _All_ in the tutorial as well, there is absolutely no need to change the default.

Comment: I thought I have to change it to cycles because when I bake it everything it renders is black but I just choose the wrong bake type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Material Output node can be set between All, Eevee and Cycles and defines which render engine the material output is intended for. This allows you to set up multiple material outputs that are tailored to a particular render engine’s strengths.

The default (all) is active in both render engines. The ‘Cycles’ setting is only active when rendering in Cycles while the ‘Eevee’ one is only active when rendering in Eevee.

However, one thing to bear in mind is that Material Preview mode is **always** rendered using Eevee. This means that by only having one Material Output node and with it set to ‘Cycles’ only, you will effectively completely disable that material in Material Preview mode.

You could add another Material Output node set to ‘Eevee’ and set up that so that it renders a suitable Eevee-friendly substitute material to use in Material Preview.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand